# compactness of imbedding problem about Gelfand triple

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V:=H_0^1(U)\cap H^2(U) $ (
Hilbert space with usual norm in $H^2(U)$) , $H:=L^2(U)$, why is $H$  compactly embedded into dual $V'$of $V$?(This is a result I know when reading a paper "parametric identification for weakly damped shallow arches" and the author gives no proof on this). I know that $V$ is compactly imbedded into $H$ by Rellich-Kondrachov theorem. More generally if $V\subset H\subset V'$is a general Gelfand triple with $V$,$H$ being Hilbert and $V$ densely continuously imbedded in $H$, if the embedding of $V$ into $H$ is compact, is the embedding $H$ into $V'$ compact?

Comment: @CaveJohnson I think your result is about the weak star topology and in this case the dual has the strong topology(norm topology).

Comment: The tranposed of a compact operator is compact (theorem of Schauder).

Comment: @Jochen Wow! This is so simple thanks to your hints.Completely solved my question.